# Spark Scala : Getting Cumulative Sum (Running Total) Using Analytical Functions

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am implementing the Cumulative Sum in Spark using Window Function.
But the order of records input is not maintained while applying the window partition function

Input data:

```
val base = List(List("10", "MILLER", "1300", "2017-11-03"), List("10", "Clark", "2450", "2017-12-9"), List("10", "King", "5000", "2018-01-28"),
  List("30", "James", "950", "2017-10-18"), List("30", "Martin", "1250", "2017-11-21"), List("30", "Ward", "1250", "2018-02-05"))
  .map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3)))

val DS1 = base.toDF("dept_no", "emp_name", "sal", "date")
DS1.show()
```

```
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|
|     10|   Clark|2450| 2017-12-9|
|     10|    King|5000|2018-01-28|
|     30|   James| 950|2017-10-18|
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|
|     30|    Ward|1250|2018-02-05|
+-------+--------+----+----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|Dept_CumSal|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|     1300.0|
|     10|   Clark|2450| 2017-12-9|     3750.0|
|     10|    King|5000|2018-01-28|     8750.0|
|     30|   James| 950|2017-10-18|      950.0|
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|     2200.0|
|     30|    Ward|1250|2018-02-05|     3450.0|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
```

I have tried the below logic

```
val baseDepCumSal = DS1.withColumn("Dept_CumSal", sum("sal").over(Window.partitionBy("dept_no").
  orderBy(col("sal"), col("emp_name"), col("date").asc).
  rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
))

baseDepCumSal.orderBy("dept_no", "date").show
```

```
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|Dept_CumSal|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|     1300.0|
|     10|   Clark|2450| 2017-12-9|     3750.0|
|     10|    King|5000|2018-01-28|     8750.0|
|     30|   James| 950|2017-10-18|     3450.0|
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|     1250.0|
|     30|    Ward|1250|2018-02-05|     2500.0|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
```

for dept_no=10, the records are computed in expected order, whereas for dept_no=30, the records were not computed in the input order.

Answer (score 9):

This happens because of incorrect types. Because salary is a `string`

```
DS1.printSchema
root
 |-- dept_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- emp_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

it is sorted lexicographically:

```
DS1.orderBy("sal").show
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|
|     30|    Ward|1250|2018-02-05|
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|
|     10|   Clark|2450| 2017-12-9|
|     10|    King|5000|2018-01-28|
|     30|   James| 950|2017-10-18|
+-------+--------+----+----------+
```

To get desired result you have to cast (and there is no need for frame definition):

```
DS1.withColumn("Dept_CumSal", sum("sal").over(
  Window
     .partitionBy("dept_no")
    .orderBy(col("sal").cast("integer"), col("emp_name"), col("date").asc))).show
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+                                  
|dept_no|emp_name| sal|      date|Dept_CumSal|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
|     30|   James| 950|2017-10-18|      950.0|
|     30|  Martin|1250|2017-11-21|     2200.0|
|     30|    Ward|1250|2018-02-05|     3450.0|
|     10|  MILLER|1300|2017-11-03|     1300.0|
|     10|   Clark|2450| 2017-12-9|     3750.0|
|     10|    King|5000|2018-01-28|     8750.0|
+-------+--------+----+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the order by inside your window `(col("sal"), col("emp_name"), col("date").asc)`, is not the same order as the the show `"dept_no", "date"`
Why do you need "sal" and "emp_name" in the window? Why not just order by date?

Answer (score 0):

Could be missing `emp_name` from the `orderBy` `baseDepCumSal.orderBy("dept_no", "date").show()`