# Cumulative function in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cumulative-sum

I have tried this to calculate  cumulate value but if the date field is same those values are added in the cumulative field, can someone suggestion solution Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607253/spark-scala-getting-cumulative-sum-running-total-using-analytical-functions/58115324?noredirect=1#comment102620260_58115324)

```
val windowval = (Window.partitionBy($"userID").orderBy($"lastModified")
             .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
val df_w_cumsum = ms1_userlogRewards.withColumn("totalRewards", sum($"noOfJumps").over(windowval)).orderBy($"lastModified".asc)
df_w_cumsum.filter($"batchType".isNull).filter($"userID"==="355163").select($"userID", $"noOfJumps", $"totalRewards",$"lastModified").show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: is this image is expected output?

Comment: no, it is not he expected output, whenever the timestamp is same value is not summed

Comment: ok got you, could you add dataframe instead of image it will make much easier.

Comment: okay, I'mnot sure to understand but I suggest a solution

Comment: have updated dataframe now u can understand, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your very first `totalRewards=147` is the sum of the previous value `49` + all the values with timestamp "2019-08-07 18:25:06": `49 + (36 + 0 + 60 + 2`) = `147`.

The first option would be to aggregate all the values with the same timestamp fist e.g. `groupBy($"userId", $"lastModified").agg(sum($"noOfJumps").as("noOfJumps"))` (or something like that) and then run your aggregate sum. This will remove duplicate timestamps altogether.

The second option is to use [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#row_number--) to define an order among rows with the same `lastModified` field first and then run your aggregate sum with `.orderBy($"lastModified, $"row_number")` (or something like that). This should keep all records and give you partial sum up along the way: `totalRewards = 49 -> 85 -> 85 -> 145 -> 147` (or something similar depending on the order defined by row_number)

Comment: thanks for suggestion will try all of both solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sum by userid and timestamp.
So, You need to partition by userid and date and use window function to sym like the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy("userID", "lastModified")
df.withColumn("cumulativeSum", sum(col("noOfJumps").over(window))
```

Comment: I tried this also it gives a different result than expected

Comment: you want by user to sum the noOfJumps if the timestamp is the same. right ?
you want to have 62 for example in the column TotalRewards ?
you need to drop duplicates after that.

Comment: it's not clear for me. because I don't see all the data may be.